# Syntax highlighting for .soy or custom file types

Tags: visual-studio-2012, syntax-highlighting, google-closure-templates

I'm using [closure templates](https://developers.google.com/closure/templates/?csw=1) to minify and generate dynamic html on my website, the only downside is that while editing in Visual Studio there's absolutely zero syntax highlighting.

Anyone know of any solutions or how to go about solving this myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Visual Studio Options - Text Editor - File Extension you can map your custom file extension to a Visual Studio editor.

Comment: That's very handy, thanks man. Are there anyways to setup your own formats for file types that don't completely match existing types? But it's a big improvement though so far.

Comment: You can create your own Visual Studio Editor Classifier or Tagger like https://github.com/tomasr/KeywordClassifier